# How to write LOG_MSSG from .sql file to shell script

Tags: sql, shell, unix, plsql

I am calling a .sql file in my shell scripting to SPOOL n no of files...
the sample look like

```
SPOOL ON;

..... -->file 1

SPOOL OFF;

SPOOL ON;

.... -->file 2

SPOOL OFF;

SPOOL ON;

.....  --> file 3

SPOOL OFF;

SPOOL ON;

....  --> file 4

SPOOL OFF;
```

Now I need to write log message in between these spools... How can I achieve that inside my .sql file?

```
log message = "No of files :x"
```

Here `:X` is a variable which will have a value of table count.

Comment: Any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `APPEND` option for `SPOOL`?

```
spool 'file1' ;
...-> file1.sql
spool off
spool 'logfile.log' ;
--> your log file
spool off
spool 'file1' APPEND;
--> file1 again
spool off
```